# Styling parent <li> and not children CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make the title, that has it's own CSS class bold. However, also the children are getting the style. Code:

```
   <ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent">
<ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    </ul>
```

So i tried to add `.cat-parent {font-weight: bold;}` however, all children are getting bold too. Same if i tried adding `:first-of-type`.

1: Why are the children getting the style, even though they don't have the css class "cat-parent"
2: What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS the child element gets the style of the parent element until a styling is specified for the child element. Example

```css
.parent{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Parent
<div class='child'>Hello<div>

</div>
```

To handle this, you must specify a style for the child; see example below.

```css
.parent{
color: red;
}

.child{
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Parent
<div class='child'> Child </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple ways to solve this.  You can add styling to the `.children` class by either doing `font-weight: normal;` or even `font-weight: initial;`.

```css
.cat-parent {
  font-weight: bold;
  }

.children {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-weight: initial;
}
```

```html
   <ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent">parent
<ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    <li class="cat-item">...</li>
    </ul>
```